# Best practice for displaying data the user might not have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I've got a Ruby on Rails app where I do the following:

```
@user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ['LOWER(username) = ?', current_subdomain.downcase], :include => :bio)
```

Where ':include => :bio' is the important part.

Then in the view I want to display some bio:

```
<em><%= @user.bio.title %></em><br />
<%= @user.bio.city %><br />
<%= @user.bio.state %><br />
<%= @user.bio.country %>
```

But if the user dosn't have any information it just will turn up a couple of blank rows.

I've tried a couple of different things, none has worked so far...

```
<% if @user.bio.title %> # is always true
<% if @user.bio.title > 0 %> # triggers an error if @user.bio.title isn't set
<% unless @user.bio.title.empty? %> # same as above
```

Any sollution to how to just display the data the user has got?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Ok, if figured some things out:

```
<% if @user.bio.title %> # Works if the bio isn't set at all.
<% if @user.bio.title > 0 %> # Works if the bio is set.
```

So I can use a sollution that looks like:

```
<% if @user.bio.title %><% if @user.bio.title > '0' %><%= @user.bio.title %><% end %><% end %>
```

But it seam a little overkill? Any better suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to think about it. *The user has a bio and has filled in the title field.* In Ruby:

```
<% if @user.bio && !@user.bio.blank? %>
```

If you are going to display multiple fields from the bio you can separate this into 2 checks e.g.

```
<% if @user.bio %>
  <% unless @user.bio.title.blank? %>
    Title: <%= @user.bio.title %>
  <% end %>
  <% unless @user.bio.other_field.blank? %>
    Other field: <%= @user.bio.other_field %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Alternative**

Another way is to put methods on your model to provide direct access to the bio fields. e.g.

```
# return the user's title or nil if no bio
def title
  bio.title if bio
end
```

Then in your view you can just do:

```
<% unless @user.title.blank? %>
  Title: <%= @user.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I like the alternative here, pull the view code out into a model code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
if defined?(@user.bio.title)
```

Comment: Seams to always return false when I tried it quickly now:

    <% if defined?(@user.bio.title) %><%= @user.bio.title %><% end %>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check out [object.try](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-object-try) or [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/)?